# Beginner Variable Declaration - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm playing around with this easy coding challenge to reverse a string:

```
function FirstReverse(str) { 
  var newStr;
  for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(str.charAt(i));
    var newStr = newStr + str.charAt(i);
  }
  return newStr;          
}
console.log(FirstReverse("hey"));
```

The result became `undefinedyeh` instead of just `yeh`. *But*, when I changed `var newStr` to `var newStr = '';`, it suddenly worked.

What data type did JavaScript think `newStr` was until I assigned it to a blank string?

Comment: You need to initialize the variable using `var newStr = '';` and don't need to redeclare it with var in for loop.

Comment: JavaScript is sometimes criticized for strange behavior with undefined or "partially" defined values. Check this out for more unpredictable results, the JavaScript starts at 1:20: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Answer (score 3):

If you don't initialize the variable, it starts as [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) (as you probably already figured out from the result).

> A variable that has not been assigned a value is of type `undefined`. A
>   method or statement also returns `undefined` if the variable that is
>   being evaluated does not have an assigned value. A function returns
>   `undefined` if a value was not returned.

Answer (score 2):

> What data type did JavaScript think `newStr` was until I assigned it to a blank string?

`var myVar;` simply declares the variable, but does not assign an initial value. The value for anything not explicitly assigned a value is `undefined`.

Since your loop is self assigning `newStr` (`newStr = newStr + str.charAt(i);`) the first iteration will try to concatenate `undefined` to itself, which in conjunction with the concatenation operand (`+`) will coerce `undefined` to `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not set a value when you initialize a variable, it is set as `undefined`.

I think it is quite advised to set a 'default value' for each initialized variable.